# Spark Parallelize? (Could not find creator property with name 'id')

Tags: serialization, apache-spark

What causes this Serialization error in Apache Spark 1.4.0 when calling:

```
sc.parallelize(strList, 4)
```

This exception is thrown:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Could not find creator property with name 'id' (in class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope)
```

Thrown from `addBeanProps` in **Jackson**: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory#addBeanProps

The RDD is a Seq[String], and the #partitions doesn't seem to matter (tried 1, 2, 4).

There is no serialization stack trace, as normal the worker closure cannot be serialized.

What is another way to track this down?

Comment: Can you add a subset of strList?

Comment: @LokeshA.R. Good question - no, same error, as soon as parallelize is called, even hard-coded as simple as `sc.parallelize(Seq("one", "two", "three"), 1)`

Comment: I changed the version of jackson-databind to 2.4.4  in my pom.xml which matches what spark 1.6 uses by default. It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

@Interfector is correct. I ran into this issue also, here's a snippet from my sbt file and the 'dependencyOverrides' section which fixed it.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-client" % "1.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % "1.4.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.2"
)

dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.4"
)
```

Comment: Great suggestion. dependencyOverride helped by revealing the proper NotSerializableException, but using databind version "2.4.0", and only after deleting several cached copies in the build directory.

Comment: This way you're hardcoding the jackson version, I believe it is better if you just exclude jackson explicitly from AWS SDK. That way, when you upgrade you won't have to think about jackson. Worst case you'll just have to remove the exclude if it is not a problem anymore.

Comment: It seems that the problem has not be fixed in spark 1.6.0, it will resolve `com.fasterxml.jackson.module#jackson-module-scala_2.11;2.4.4`

Comment: This problem also occurs with Play 2.4, and this fix here still works for it.

Comment: Here we are at spark-core 1.6.0, this fix is still great +1

Answer (score 10):

I suspect that this is caused by the classpath providing you with a different version of `jackson` than the one Spark is expecting (that is **2.4.4** if I'm not mistaking). You will need to adjust your classpath so that the correct `jackson` is referenced first for Spark.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Can you elaborate more on that? If spark 1.4.0 is downloaded from ivy, doesn't that uber-jar contain the appropriate version of jackson-databind?

Comment: Spark might contain the right jackson version, but depending on the priority in the classpath, it might not be the first version that the ClassLoader picks up. One way you could do it is to use spark submit and put your uber jar at the end of the classpath. That way Spark's jackson will be loaded first. The problem is that is theory, it could cause problems for the AWS SDK, since it will too use the older version, which might be problematic, especially if there's no binary compatibility.

Comment: Excellent suggestion by Interfector. I had the same issue when using spark 1.6. jackson-databind 2.4.4 mvn dependency completely resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a project built with Gradle and I excluded the transitive dependencies from the project that was creating the problem:

```
dependencies
{
    compile('dependency.causing:problem:version')
    {
        exclude module: 'jackson-databind'
    }

....

}
```

That worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `<dependency> excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core")`