# Running spark-redshift from Intellij using Gradle

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the spark-redshift library and am unable to operate on the dataframe created by the sqlContext.read() command (reading from redshift).

Here is my code:

```
Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver")

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Application").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "****")

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "****") 

val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://URL")
  .option("dbtable", "table")
  .option("tempdir", "s3n://bucket/folder")
  .load()

df.registerTempTable("table")
val data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table")

data.show()
```

And this is the error I receive when running the above code within a main method in a scala object:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:709)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1096)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.buildScan(RedshiftRelation.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$3.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$3.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:274)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.planLater(QueryPlanner.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$BasicOperators$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:374)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:924)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:930)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:930)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1903)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1384)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1314)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:370)
at com.triplelift.spark.Main$.main(Main.scala:37)
at com.triplelift.spark.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

If this helps, I also have my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile (
        'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.31',
        'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:1.10.31',
        'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.5.1',
        'org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.10:1.5.1',
        'org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:1.5.1',
        'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.10:1.5.1',
        'com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:0.5.2',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3'
    )

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Needless to say, the error occurs when data.show() is evaluated.

On an unrelated note... Anyone using Intellij 14 know how to add the Redshift driver to the modules permanently? It gets wiped from Dependencies in Project Structure every time I do a gradle refresh. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original issue was getting this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Could not find creator property with name 'id' (in class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope)
```

So I followed this answer here:

[Spark Parallelize? (Could not find creator property with name 'id')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039367/spark-parallelize-could-not-find-creator-property-with-name-id)

So I added this line 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3' and switched between different versions (i.e. 2.4.4) and then began looking at my external libraries in the project view... So I removed the new jackson-databind dependency and wanted to see all the jackson libraries that spark loads... That's when I noticed that the jackson libraries were all 2.5.1 except for jackson-module-scala_2.10, which was on 2.4.4 - so instead of fudging around with the jackson-databind dependency, I added this:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:2.6.3'
```

And now my code works. Seems like spark-core 1.51 wasn't built properly before being put into maven? Not sure.

NOTE: Always check your transitive dependencie and their versions...