# Jackson version is too old

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have the following `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "myProject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")


dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.1"
)

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.4.0",
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.4",
  "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.0.0_0.4.4" % "test",
)
```

However, when I am running the code, I get this error:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort. 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.4.4
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:56)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:549)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    ... 58 more
```

Why is this the case?
I've added a newer version of Jackson to `dependencyOverrides`(after looking here [Spark Parallelize? (Could not find creator property with name 'id')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039367/spark-parallelize-could-not-find-creator-property-with-name-id)), so an older version shouldn't be used.

Comment: It must be something else that's pulling in the older version as a dependency.  You'll need to find what that is and get a version of it that is up to date with Jackson.  Maven would make this easy to figure out.

Comment: Try to add jackson dependency in `libraryDependencies` with ` force()` at the end: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq( ... "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.1" force()`

Answer (score 3):

jackson-core and jackson-databind versions should match (at least up to the minor version, I believe).

So remove the `dependencyOverrides` and have

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.1"
)
```

Or specify both in `dependencyOverrides`

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.1"
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.1"
)
```

Though I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do; the linked question seems to say that you should used an older version (2.4.4).