# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.4

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to read data from MongoDB and place it in HDFS.
But I'm getting the error:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Jackson version is too old 2.5.4  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:56)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:653)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala)
>     .......

Please help to resolve this

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686318/jackson-version-is-too-old

Comment: The above one is in Scala. But i'm looking for Java :)